# trouble changing variable, jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a variable I define as default_gym.  In an onclick I change the variable.  The problem is when I then reference the variable in the function menu_expand through the hover the variable hasn't change, or rather the div '#newburyport' isn't taking the css.

```
var default_gym;

$('.intro_circle').on('click', function () {
  if ($(this).is("#intro_newburyport")) {
    var default_gym = 'newburyport';
  }
});




function menu_expand() {
     $('#'+default_gym).css({
        color:"#ffffff"
     });
}


$('#menu-wrapper').hover(
  function() {
    if ( $('#menu-wrapper').hasClass('safe_hover')) {
      menu_expand();
    }
  },
  function() {
    if ( $('#menu-wrapper').hasClass('safe_hover')) {
      menu_collapse();  
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new variable inside the click function. Remove `var` to assign a value to your existing global variable

Comment: so I tried this, for some reason it still doesn't allow for the new value to be used in the function with the hover.

Comment: to provide a better solution please post your HTML, or better yet a fiddle that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "var" within the jQuery method:

```
$('.intro_circle').on('click', function () {
  if ($(this).is("#intro_newburyport")) {
    default_gym = 'newburyport';
  }
});
```

Comment: so I tried this, for some reason it still doesn't allow for the new value to be used in the function with the hover.